# role of authorization header in jwt authentication in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, authorization, jwt

https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Authentication
Referring to this documentation, how to set:
Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere}
For every get request made from frontend? And how to get username or other details once header is set for current logged in user?
P.S. we are not using angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

When you route your request to your controller functions, your function must return a response, where you can set the header.

For example: 
    return response()->header('key', value)

Username and details can be passed in the content of the response, or fetched from database.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned your fronted technology but  Authorization: Bearer {yourtokenhere} should be set in the request header for every secure API call. You can use the fronted interceptor to intercept the request and append the  Authorization Bearer token in the request header for Secure APIs.
And you can parse the token and get the details like user name, scope at client side as well as server side.

Comment: I'm working on Laravel (Blade) with frontend using css, bootstrap, js

Comment: Please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250569/laravel-send-api-token-within-the-header