# send api_token through header instead of query parameter

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-5

I am trying to build APIS in laravel 5.6, and for api authentication I am using laravel basic API token authentication.

For get request or post request, I need to pass `api_token` in the query parameter. Is there any way where I can pass the `api_token` in the header instead of url string?

I followed [Laravel - Send api_token within the header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250569/laravel-send-api-token-within-the-header) .

For GET endpoint, my api url is like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/category-list?api_token=YDYsOgkSIOWDdE1NG3Ih1yCkciatOPvtpF1gXTmy8GL1r72mcDEgNDkkZ5jh&Accept=application%2Fjson
```

For POST my parameter are like this

[image]

As you can see, for get I need to add the api token in the url, and for POST I need to add in the body.
If I add the api token in the header, it says unauthorized access.

Header setting where authorization does not work
[image]

Comment: please add code or request example to your question.

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy hi, i updated the question with end point and image

Comment: @user7747472 For your get and post request what are you using to send the request on the client side? Something like ```axios```?

Comment: @user7747472 your updates don't help because you show request that works. Please show headers section for request where authorization doesn't work.

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy i added another screenshot where authorization does not work.

Comment: @LeonVismer, Yes currently i am testing using post man but eventually i will use it with axios in react native application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you send api token through header the name of the header should be `Authorization` not `api_token`.
Also prepend the type of token `Bearer` to authorization header.

So finally the header should look like:

`Authorization: Bearer aEzKClugYHJQsr6If48i1y24KneTT7YwMtNrri7JNhGyEIbJv6YP5SrsFXx2`